# How to predict label of new dataset, when it does not cover all features of the training set?

Tags: r, text-mining

I am new to textmining.

I have a dataset of SMS and I want to learn if something is spam or not. I used quanteda to transform my text content into a matrix of words. I also removed stopwords, converted the words to wordstems and trained a model with

`rpart.cv.1 <- train(Label ~ ., data = train_tokens_df, method = "rpart", trControl = cv_cntrl, tuneLength = 5)`.

Now I want to predict the label of testdata. I did all the preprocessing steps I did with the train data. The problem is, I have words in my train data that the test data does not cover.

My guess is, that the next step should be to add all the columns of the training data that are missing in the test data. But how to do that in an easy and efficient way? Train and test are both dataframes in my case.

Comment: You can use stratified sampling to make sure each word has some train and test rows. Also, first consider what are you going to do with words that appear only once. Those will definitely belong to either the train or test data.

Comment: I have done stratified sampling, but know I want to predict data that I don't know the label of.

Comment: If you don't have a label in your train data it's not possible to train the model on those rows. If you don't have a label in your train data you won't be possible to examine the accuracy of those rows. Label is your target variable if I understood correctly, right? Why not excluding rows with no target variable? They cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some trick with `data.table`, but if you have two `data.frame` and just want to "subset" the second one to the column names of the first one, filling in missing columns, you can do the following:

```
orig = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)  # example data
new  = data.frame(a = 7:9, c = 11:13)  # missing the 'b' column

# first insert new columns that are still missing in 'new':
new[setdiff(colnames(orig), colnames(new))] = 0  # NA, or whatever
# now subset the new dataset to the columns of the old one
new = new[colnames(orig)]
```

This gives you

```
> new
  a b
1 7 0
2 8 0
3 9 0
```

Note that this only works with `data.frame`, not with `matrix`, so if you have a matrix you need to do

```
new = as.data.frame(new)
```

first.